Un énorme [ … ] de course
Dans cette vidéo après la trente-quatrième  seconde, je n'arrive pas à comprendre un groupe nominal : un mot très bref semblerait être « pet » dans « un énorme [ … ] de course » mais je n'ai jamais entendu ce terme et le principe d'attribution de sens par analogie ne me semble pas appartenir au français. Si ce terme était nouveau, pourrait-on expliquer son origine et ajouter des informations sur le registre, etc.?

Je n'entends pas le son [p] mais [f], « fait »?  « fait de course » ferait sens dans le contexte (évènement/incident). Ça pourra être « effet », ce qui pour moi fait moins sens. Quelqu'un qui maîtrise mieux que moi le vocabulaire du reportage sportif rétablira probablement sans hésitation.

C'est bien "fait de course" qui est prononcé. Ça désigne une faute, un évènement malencontreux causant litige, qui s'est passé pendant une course.
Comparer à "fait de jeu", utilisé dans d'autres sports (notamment en football).
Chercher "fait de course" l'équipe  sur google retourne pas mal de résultats, par exemple celui-ci.

Un choix quand même plus judicieux.

+1: "ça bouscule!" s'exclament les commentateurs après 00:11. Dommage, un pet de course eût été tellement plus poétique: https://www.amazon.fr/HAPINARY-Hamster-Silencieux-Course-Exercice/dp/B0D4JZ78FH
